# Python: why how/where/where np.where

Tags: numpy, where-clause

I see discussion of numpy's 'where' function all over the place but I still do not understand.

I have arrays/lists of thousands of (x,y,z) vectors ( x,y and z, between -1 and 1) I need those vectors where, say, y is < .25, z > .90. and x is not == 0.

How would you do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired input/output, in the correct types and shape?

Answer (score 1):

There are two uses of `np.where`, one with 1 argument, and the other with 3.  It sounds like you are interested in the 1 argument case, which is just another name for `np.nonzero`.

You mention `vectors`, so I assume you are interested in 1d arrays, not the slightly more complicated case of 2d or higher.

Here are 2 basic examples:

```
In [320]: np.where([1, 0, .2, 3, .222, 0])
Out[320]: (array([0, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32),)
```

Note that 1 and 5 are missing - those are indices of the 0's.

```
In [321]: np.nonzero([True, False, False, True])
Out[321]: (array([0, 3], dtype=int32),)
```

0 and 3 are the indices of the 2 True values.

A `where` or `nonzero` involving `y is < .25, z > .90. and x is not == 0` reduces the finding the indices of the True values of that logical expression,

```
(y < .25) & (z > .90) & (x != 0)
```

So if you wonder what the `where/nonzero` is doing, first look at the True/False vales of the `condition` expression.  All it is doing is telling us `where` that expression is true.

```
In [327]: x=np.linspace(-2,2,5); y=np.linspace(0,1,5); z=np.linspace(.5,1,5)
In [328]: (y<.25)&(z>.9)&(x!=0)
Out[328]: array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [329]: (y<.25)|(z>.9)|(x!=0)
Out[329]: array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [330]: np.where((y<.25)|(z>.9)|(x!=0))
Out[330]: (array([0, 1, 3, 4], dtype=int32),)
```

Now dealing with 'thousands of vectors' becomes more complicated.  Are those 'vectors' independent, or are they 'rows' of 2d arrays or what?

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like this (example):

```
['17:54:03:421801', -0.714, 0.0114, 0.196]
['17:54:03:438803', 0.312, -0.0244, 0.312]
['17:54:03:444301', 0.137, -0.263, 0.908]
[...etc...]
```

The time stamp is not really a primary concern but it needs to be kept. A small file might be 10,000 'rows' and have multiple files daily. So, I need the indices of 'where', say ,  y is < .25 and  z > .90. and x != 0.

Or more generally: where a1 and a2 and a3.

How should this be approached? What would who do with this? Time is much more important than memory usage. I would like to do this in Python but should I just jump to c, my native language?

Clues? Thoughts? Suggestions?